# How can I get my print statement to work to where it prints the average score and the correlating letter grade?

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // Defining the constants for min and max range
        final int minValue = -1;
        final int maxValue = 100;
        String message = "Welcome to Simple Gradebook!";

        promptForInt(message, minValue, maxValue);

        // Declaring variables for the loop & the sentinel variable
        int score = 0;
        boolean doneYet = false;

        do
        {
            // Input Validation
            if (score < minValue || score > maxValue)
            {
                System.err.printf("Invalid value. The acceptable range is"
                        + " between %d and %d\n"
                        + "Please try again\n", minValue, maxValue);
            }
            else
            {
                doneYet = true;
            }
        } while (doneYet == false);

    }

    public static int promptForInt(String message, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        // Declaring variables for the loop & the sentinel variable
        int sum = 0;
        int numStudents = 0;
        int score = 0;

        System.out.println(message);

        //Creating the sentinel loop
        do
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter the score for student #%d"
                    + "(or -1 to quit): ", numStudents);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            score = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());

            if (score != -1)
            {
                sum += score;
                numStudents += 1;
            }

        } while (score != -1);
        double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;
       
        //Passing method to this method to convert grade to letter
        convertToLetter(avgScore);
        System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore
                + " which equates to a " + avgScore);
        return 0;

    }

    public static char convertToLetter(double avg)
    {
        char avgScore = 0;
        // Identifying the ranges for the grade letter
        if (avgScore >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
        else if (avg >= 80)
        {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
        else if (avg >= 70)
        {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
        else if (avg >= 60)
        {
            System.out.println("D");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("F");
        }
        return avgScore;

    }
}
```

How can I get my print statement to work to where it prints the average score and the correlating letter grade? Like this... “The average score is 90.5, which equates to an A”

My input validation is not working like it should for some reason. If a number lower that -1 or higher than 100 is entered, it should give the error message and begin the loop again.

Comment: ``double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;`` needs to be ``double avgScore = ((double sum) / numstudents;`` in order to prevent integer division.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your programs. If you are using an IDE then it should have a debugger. You should learn how to use it. For now, just one piece of advice regarding the code in your question. Don't create a new `Scanner` on each loop iteration. Create the `Scanner` **before** you enter the loop.

Comment: @NomadMaker incorrect. `(double) sum / numStudents` *first* casts `sum` to `double`, which makes the division operation and result `double`. OP’s code (here anyway) is fine.

Comment: @abra I need to declare "score" before I can use it, that's why it's set to 0. My code is not performing the input validation if score is always 0.

Comment: @Bohemian yes, the integer division is not my problem.  Any ideas to get the letter grade to show in the print statement?

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash I tried that as well before... the statement prints like this: C (then in a new line) "The average score is.....  The letter grade will not print in the statement like it should, instead it prints on top

Comment: @Brown - Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188888/10819573) and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Allow me to recommend the book [Java by Comparison](https://www.amazon.com/Java-Comparison-Become-Craftsman-Examples/dp/1680502875)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are not assigning and returning the grade letter from the function, `convertToLetter` correctly.
2. You are not printing the return value of the function, `convertToLetter`.

Write the function as shown below:

```
public static char convertToLetter(double avg) {
    char gradeLetter;
    // Identifying the ranges for the grade letter
    if (avg >= 90) {
        gradeLetter = 'A';
    } else if (avg >= 80) {
        gradeLetter = 'B';
    } else if (avg >= 70) {
        gradeLetter = 'C';
    } else if (avg >= 60) {
        gradeLetter = 'D';
    } else {
        gradeLetter = 'F';
    }
    return gradeLetter;
}
```

and then change the print statement as `System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore + " which equates to a " + convertToLetter(avgScore));`

Comment: thank you so much! I see now how the method and passing avgScore as the Arthur is working!

Comment: do you have an idea of how to get my input validation to work the way I have it written? I tired to add the line of code "score = promtForInt (message, minValue, maxValue) after the error message but that didn't work

Comment: @Brown - Yes, it's easy to do. If you don't mind, I would suggest you post a new question for validation problem so that this question/answer doesn't get polluted.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not doing anything with the result of `convertToLetter(avgScore)`.

Assign the result to a variable:

```
char grade = convertToLetter(avgScore);
```

Then refer to that variable when printing:

```
System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore
  + " which equates to a " + grade);
```

—--

You have a similar problem when calling `promptForInt(message, minValue, maxValue)`; you need to assign the result to a variable:

```
score = promptForInt(message, minValue, maxValue);
```

Another major bug you have is your input checking code. If `score` is not in range, your `do while` loop will loop infinitely because the value of `score` is not changed anywhere inside the loop.

Add this line after printing the error message:

```
score = promptForInt(message, minValue, maxValue);
```

—--

In general, you must realise that variables have *scope*. You assigning a value to the `avgScore` variable declared inside the `convertToLetter` method has no effect whatsoever on the variable of the same name declared in your main method - they are different variables, whose scope is limited to the method in which they are declared.

Comment: I see what you're saying about assigning it to a variable, thank you. I did those changes, yet the letter grade still does not show up in the print statement

Comment: Did you notice that I modified the print statement to include `grade`?

Comment: yes I did see the modified print statement, thank you.  So, with the input validation,  I understand now what you are saying about not having a variable that changes the range of "score". I tried putting score = promptForInt (message, minValue, maxValue) directly after my err message and I'm still getting the same thing.

Comment: I am under the impression that my loop is not reading the boolean like it should

Answer (score 0):

This code works. Explanations after.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Defining the constants for min and max range
        final int minValue = -1;
        final int maxValue = 100;

        String message = "Welcome to Simple Gradebook!";
        System.out.println(message);

        // Declaring variables for the loop & the sentinel variable
        int score = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int numStudents = 0;

        while (true) {
            score = promptForInt(keyboard, (numStudents + 1), minValue, maxValue);
            if (score == -1) {
                break;
            }
            sum += score;
            numStudents++;
        }
        if (numStudents == 0) {
            System.out.println("No data received.");
        }
        else {
            double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;
            char letter = convertToLetter(avgScore);
            System.out.printf("The average score is: %.3f which equates to a %c%n",
                              avgScore,
                              letter);
        }
    }

    public static int promptForInt(Scanner keyboard, int numStudent, int minValue, int maxValue) {
        // Declaring variables for the loop & the sentinel variable
        int score = 0;
        boolean isValidScore = false;

        // Creating the sentinel loop
        do {
            System.out.printf("Enter the score for student #%d (or -1 to quit): ", numStudent);
            String line = keyboard.nextLine();
            try {
                score = Integer.parseInt(line);
                if (score < minValue || score > maxValue) {
                    System.out.printf("Invalid value. Acceptable range is between %d and %d%n",
                                      minValue,
                                      maxValue);
                }
                else {
                    isValidScore = true;
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                System.out.printf("Not a number: %s%n", line);
            }
        } while (!isValidScore);
        return score;
    }

    public static char convertToLetter(double avg) {
        char avgScore = 0;
        // Identifying the ranges for the grade letter
        if (avg >= 90) {
            avgScore = 'A';
        }
        else if (avg >= 80) {
            avgScore = 'B';
        }
        else if (avg >= 70) {
            avgScore = 'C';
        }
        else if (avg >= 60) {
            avgScore = 'D';
        }
        else {
            avgScore = 'F';
        }
        return avgScore;
    }
}
```

Method `promptForInt()` should accept a single score from the user and return it. It should return only a valid score.

Method `main()` contains the loop for gathering up all the scores.

You need to check that at least one score was entered, otherwise you can't calculate the average.

Method `convertToLetter()` was always assigning the value zero to `avgScore`, essentially making `avgScore` the null character.

Here is a sample run of the program.

```
Welcome to Simple Gradebook!
Enter the score for student #1 (or -1 to quit): 66
Enter the score for student #2 (or -1 to quit): 66
Enter the score for student #3 (or -1 to quit): 68
Enter the score for student #4 (or -1 to quit): -1
The average score is: 66.667 which equates to a D
```

Comment: yes, this code works thank you. I'd like to figure out why my input validation wasn't working. I signed a value to "score" after the error message and the input validation will didn't work